# What ports are needed for DNS WMI calls

Tags: dns, wmi, ports

I am working on a c# .net 4.0 web app that will use WMI to manipulate DNS records and need to know what ports need to be opened up to it. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DNS runs on port 53
All WMI calls use RPC on port 135